Engineering Dynamics Problem (Newton's Method vs. Energy and Momentum Methods)
Sorry to bother everyone,this is my first time posting on this forum.
I am currently conducting a study on landing gear mechanisms, specifically focusing on optimizing their dynamic performance. I am facing some issues and would like to seek your advice.
According to relevant information, the drive torque obtained using Newton's method and the Energy and Momentum Method should usually be the same.
However, while performing Kinetics analysis, the torque values calculated using the two methods are not the same.
First, analyze using a single link rather than multiple linkages.Here are my free body diagram and mass acceleration diagram.

According to these diagrams, drive torque formula can be defined as:

I assume this linkage operates at a constant speed, so the angular acceleration during operation is zero.
input Data:

(1) Newton's Method
Ti = W1*rG1*cos_θ1 = 2*9.81*0.075*cos150° = -1.274 N-m

(2) Energy  and Momentum Methods
IF θ1 = 120°~150° Find torque at θ1 =150° (Δθ1=30°=(1/6)π)
(Ek1+Ug1)+ΔW=(Ek2+Ug2),ΔW=Ti*Δθ1
Ti = [(Ek2+Ug2)-(Ek1+Ug1)]/Δθ1
Ek2-Ek1=0 (because angular velocity is constant.)
Ug2-Ug1 = m1*g*rG1*(sin150°-sin120°)=2*9.81*0.075*-0.366=-0.5386
Ti = -0.5386/(1/6)π=-1.0286 N-m

From the above, it can be seen that the results obtained from the two methods are different. Can someone help me clarify this issue?Thanks.

Will the weight $m_1$ produce a constant torque in the range 120° to 150°? It seems to me like you are calculating torque at 150° in the first method, but some kind of mean torque between 120° and 150° in the second method. You could try the second calculation with very close angles, like 149° and 150°, to see if the result gets closer to the first method.

Thank you for your reply. I think I misunderstood. What I need to calculate is the instantaneous driving torque when the linkage moves to 150 degrees. I will try it according to your method.
